# Tricky callback realization (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, closures

I have been trying to think out a lightweight class which would delegate static/member functions, functors, closures, etc. In my project, it is necessary to pass such the entities as function arguments, and in addition, this is used in some other cases.

The first time, I decided to use templates and inheritance and got something like this:

```cpp
template<class ReturnType, class ...Args>
class callback {
private:

    //
    struct abstract_invoker {
        virtual ReturnType invoke(Args...) = 0;
    };

    //
    template<class Function>
    class sf_invoker : public abstract_invoker {
    public:
        sf_invoker(Function function) : _function(function) { };

        ReturnType invoke(Args ...args) override {
            return _function(args...);
        }

    private:
        Function _function;
    };

    //
    template<class Class>
    class mf_invoker : public abstract_invoker {
        using Function = ReturnType (Class::*)(Args...);

    public:
        mf_invoker(Class& target, Function function) : _target(target), _function(function) { };

        ReturnType invoke(Args ...args) override {
            return (_target.*_function)(args...);
        }

    private:
        Class&      _target;
        Function    _function;
    };

// --------------------------------------
public:
    template<class Function>
    callback(Function function) {
        _invoker = new sf_invoker<Function>(function);
    }
    template<class Class>
    callback(Class& object, ReturnType(Class::*function)(Args...)) {
        _invoker = new mf_invoker<Class>(object, function);
    }
    ~callback() {
        delete _invoker;
    }

    ReturnType operator() (Args ...args) {
        return _invoker->invoke(args...);
    }

private:
    abstract_invoker* _invoker;
};
```

Actually, this method solves my problem but it works a bit slow. I tried to avoid virtual functions and *empirically* discovered that the code below works as well (VS 2014):

```cpp
template<class ReturnType, class ...Args>
class callback {
    using Function = ReturnType (*)(Args...);

public:
    template<class _Function>
    callback(_Function function) {
        auto invoker = [function] (Args ...args) -> ReturnType {
            return function(args...);
        };

        _invoker = &invoker;
    }
    template<class _Class>
    callback(_Class& object, ReturnType (_Class::*function)(Args...)) {
        auto invoker = [function, &object] (Args ...args) -> ReturnType {
            return (object.*function)(args...);
        };

        _invoker = &invoker;
    }

    ReturnType operator()(Args ...args) {
        return (*(Function*) _invoker)(args...);
    }

private:
    void* _invoker;
};
```

Obviously, this implementation works faster. Such the method is not safe, but I do not know the standard very well, so I do not know the compiler requirements for lambda expressions. So my question is: *Is it magic? Or would it work on the most of compilers?*

Comment: It's undefined behaviour throughout.

Comment: Why don't you just use std::function?

Comment: The amount of `new` without `delete` is too high..

Comment: @ChristianHackl I am just a student, and it is my task. Unfortunately, I should avoid using STL. :)

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames Fixed. Anyway, it does not change the fact.

Comment: An inner lambda function is not created with every call to the containing function. Thus I am willing to say that the last segment of code will work fine. Seeing as you're taking the address of it and all.

Comment: Regarding the second example: why `void* _invoker;` when `Function _invoker;` would be fine ? Also, note that you are forbidden to use `_Class`, identifiers of the form `_[A-Z]\w*` and `\w*__\w*` are reserved to the implementation in any scope, and identifiers of the form `_[a-z]\w*` are reserved to the implementation in the global scope.

Comment: @MatthieuM. This code was written just for an example. Actually, there is no difference if I reinterpret lambda to `Function` in the constructor or right before the call.

Comment: @alphashooter: Normally I would expect an error for the statement `Function x = invoker;` stating that `invoker` cannot be converting to `Function`.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I knowingly converted the address of the lambda to `Function*`, just to see what would happen. I used this convertion on my own risk and wondered that it worked.

Comment: @alphashooter: I advise against it. The problem with *undefined behavior* is that it's just that *undefined*. It may seem to work for a while, it may crash, it may give seemingly random results, ... in short it's unpredictable and therefore observations are usually worthless.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I agree, you are right. There is no doubt. :) It was unclear for me, so it was the reason why I asked this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has an issue of lifetime: you have to think of the scope in which objects are valid (and after which they are dead).

```
template<class Func>
callback(Func function) {
    auto invoker = [function] (Args ...args) -> ReturnType {
        return function(args...);
    };

    _invoker = &invoker;
}
```

`invoker` captures state, therefore cannot be transformed into a pointer to function. If `_invoker` were typed as `Function` the compiler would probably warn you.

The remark is the same for the second overload.

So, if it works, it's accidental.